# Problem with AWS API Gateway websocket- Lambda postToConnection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've been trying to solve this problem all day, looking everywhere on the web, even in the official AWS documentation, why does this error keep appearing when I try to send a message to the client through this code?

PS. i use SDK v3 with node.js 18

```
import {
  ApiGatewayManagementApiClient,
  PostToConnectionCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi";

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const domain = event.requestContext.domainName;
  const stage = event.requestContext.stage;
  const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  const callbackUrl = `https://${domain}/${stage}`;
  const client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({ endpoint: callbackUrl });

  const requestParams = {
    ConnectionId: connectionId,
    Data: "Hello!",
  };

  const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(requestParams);

  try {
    await client.send(command);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
  };
};
```

```
 fef17825-58ce-4ca7-8f38-85857f1aef0a Task timed out after 3.01 seconds
```

i tried any online guide or video, can anyone help me?

Comment: Did any request ever get through?

Comment: no, never.... connection failed from client
but if i send something from client to server it receives it, but if i want to send from server to client i can't server can only reply through return but can't send anything

Comment: i have increment the timeout with 3 mins and the result:
{"message": "Endpoint request timed out",

Answer (score 0):

I do copy and paste your code to my gateway, everything works fine.

```
import {
  ApiGatewayManagementApiClient,
  PostToConnectionCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi";

export const handler = async(event) => {
  const domain = event.requestContext.domainName;
  const stage = event.requestContext.stage;
  const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
  const callbackUrl = `https://${domain}/${stage}`;
  const client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient({ endpoint: callbackUrl });

  const requestParams = {
    ConnectionId: connectionId,
    Data: "Hello!",
  };

  const command = new PostToConnectionCommand(requestParams);

  try {
    await client.send(command);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
  };
};
```

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxPlY.png)

P.S. Did you add the `AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess` for your gateway function (Lambda -> Functions -> yourHandler -> Configuration -> Execution role -> Permissions -> add AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess)?

Comment: How actually you would do that, at least I coulnd't see options there?